# mysql 1-abs(sign(x)) paradigm

Tags: mysql

Looking at an old MySQL query, I found the following paradigm:

```
colTwo*(1-abs(sign(colOne-3)))
```

To include the value of `colTwo` when the value of `colOne` was 3 (3 is an example)

With a more recent MySQL version, this has started failing because `colOne` is unsigned, and it complains that for cases where `colOne` is 1 or 2 the expression becomes negative.

It seems to work by replacing with:

```
colTwo*(colOne=3)
```

Because the comparison appears to return 1 or 0 the same as the previous expression

Can anyone enlighten a (relative) MySQL novice as to why the abs(sign(x)) paradigm would have been used, rather than the straight comparison operation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the likely alternative to the expression might involve a `CASE` expression looking something like the following:

```
CASE WHEN colOne = 3 THEN colTwo ELSE 0 END
```

The way it is written now is more concise.  So the explanation I offer is that the original form, and your workaround, were chosen because they were relatively lean ways of expressing the logic you want.

Comment: The resulting statement was also then nested inside an `if` statement in the real code. I saw comments elsewhere while researching this that suggest that nesting `if` and `case` don't always work well/correctly - is that true?
This doesn't explain why the abs(sign(x)) notation was considered necessary by the original author though

Comment: Please post the actual code/query.  When I answered I assumed the context was a regular query and not a proc or something else.

Answer (score 0):

It may have been used to create a crosstab (Pivot table) in a unique way with a select statement.  Here is a solid explanation and information on this method.

[Pivot table with select statemetn](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30849542)